# How to test than an XML string is well formed in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I'm looking for some code in .net to allow me to test an xml file to determine if it is well-formed.   I am not validating the file against a schema at this point in my code, just testing that it conforms to xml specification for being well formed.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check well-formed XML without a try/catch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026247/check-well-formed-xml-without-a-try-catch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try parsing the XML into an XMLDocument and see if it throws.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  After asking the above question, I found this stackoverflow question that didn't show up in my initial search:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026247/check-well-formed-xml-without-a-try-catch