# How validate xml-fragment in Silverlight without thrown Exception?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, validation, exception

I need method like

```
public bool IsValid(string xmlText) {
 // validation xml
}
```

I can write code like:

```
public bool IsValid(string xmlText) {
  try {
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText), settings);
    while (reader.Read());
  }
  catch {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But I want write code without thrown exception. How I can do it?

Comment: Why exactly is the thrown exception a problem?  Is it not functioning correctly?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026247/check-well-formed-xml-without-a-try-catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom Validation. Pretty simple to implement.

- [RIA Services and
  Validation](http://www.nikhilk.net/RIA-Services-Validation.aspx)
- [Data Validation with Silverlight 3 and the

  DataForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335695.aspx)