# read xml in vb net passing crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i need this to automatically vallidate the xml file. no need to verify it. so how?

```
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\Purchase Request Setup\Crystal reports\crptPurchaseRequest.xml")
```

is this how to read xml?

or

```
 dt.ReadXml("C:\Purchase Request Setup\Crystal reports\crptPurchaseRequest.xml")
```

Comment: Validate the XML against what? Do you want to ensure that the XML is valid XML or do you want to validate the file against an XSD?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to validate XML...

```
Public Shared Function IsValidXml(xmlString As String) As Boolean
    Dim tagsWithData As New Regex("<\w+>[^<]+</\w+>")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString) OrElse tagsWithData.IsMatch(xmlString) = False Then
        Return False
    End If

    Try
        Dim xmlDocument As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString)
        Return True
    Catch xmlException As XmlException
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

N.B. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835251/1350913)

Or you could simply handle the exception

```
Try
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\Purchase Request Setup\Crystal reports\crptPurchaseRequest.xml")
Catch ex As XmlException 'Handle the exception
    'Probably poorly formed XML...
End Try
```